# Fonts working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, fonts

I am using `imagettftext()` for creating text over a image. I used times new roman font, the application in working fine on my development machine but not in live environment.

Please adivce. Is it due to my dev. machine in windows and live is linux ?

Please Help

Actual problem is text on my locahost appears "Monster" but on live server "Mo nster" this is not only  with O but with other alphabets too...

```
$font = './fonts/times.ttf';    

$bbox = imagettfbbox(30, 0, $font, $word);

$x = $bbox[0] + (imagesx($src) / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2);
$y = $bbox[1] + (imagesy($src) / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2)+212;

imagettftext($src, 30, 0, $x, $y, $color, $font, $word);

$bbox2 = imagettfbbox(18, 0, $font, $definition);

$x = $bbox2[0] + (imagesx($src) / 2) - ($bbox2[4] / 2);
$y = $bbox2[1] + (imagesy($src) / 2) - ($bbox2[5] / 2)+245;

imagettftext($src, 18, 0, $x, $y, $white, $font, $definition);
```

Comment: Does apache have permissions to read the files/directory where the fonts are?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, and in my case the problem was the font definition extension. It was ttf, not Ttf. Check the case of your file extension.

Comment: imez above has the right idea - I would mark it up if I could. Thing is windows doesn't care about file extensions case, a Linux server however does. This is probably why it works locally and not live. Lee. - Digital Acorn Ltd.

Answer (score 0):

yes , probably the font is not installed on the linux server (live)

Comment: I have used the font file in my website directory and reflected it path in the function

Comment: try `$font = 'fonts/times.ttf';` or `$font = '../fonts/times.ttf';`   and try to get the full path (`echo realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);`

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out a long back, the issue was with php version & As I saw a bug reported regarding the problem & quick fix too

Links are added below

Bug:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51571

Solution: (without changing PHP version)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php (see solution by sk89q)

Thanks